# Firebase Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase UI-Auth for authentication but after adding analytics dependency I'm getting this error. The app crashes after some time being idle. Sometimes it crashes at the initial start up after restarting it couple of times it runs fine. I have also updated all the libraries to their latest versions but this also doesn't help.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError No field
>   PREFER_HIGHEST_OR_REMOTE_VERSION_NO_FORCE_STAGING of type
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule$VersionPolicy; in
>   class Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule; or its
>   superclasses (declaration of
>   'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule' appears in base.apk)

This is my build.gradle

```
    import com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hussain.podcastapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.devlight.navigationtabstrip:navigationtabstrip:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:glidepalette:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.6.1'
    implementation "com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.9"
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.8.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-beta02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-beta02'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

This is my project level build.gradle

```
    buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: No, it eventually went away. I don't have any idea how

Comment: i think you don't have check user null of not "firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();"